# How to create a spread/range of consecutive dates in Azure data factory in derived transformation

Tags: datetime, azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I want to create a date spread from 01-01-2005 till 23-01-2015, is it possible to populate such a dates range in the Azure data factory (specifically in mapping data flows). If yes then which function should one use to apply the same.

Thank you!

Comment: The best way to do this is use a date dimension in your database and then do a simple Lookup activity or Mapping Data Flows equivalent.

Comment: Please be sure to show your work and where, specifically, you're stuck. Unfortunately, this question is too broad as written (there's no specific problem).

Comment: you can create a list in the pipeline and pass it as a parameter to the flow. No need for a database. https://medium.com/geekculture/create-an-array-of-dates-for-looping-in-azure-data-factory-da148e01bc10

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Until activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity) to loop through start and end dates and add append variable activity to append the dates to get the range of dates.

1. Create a bunch of variables for start date, end date, number of days to be appended.

[image]

2. Until activity:

[image]

increment day by 1 : `@string(add(int(variables('add_count')),1))`

days to add : `@variables('count')`

Append date to list : `@formatdatetime(adddays(formatdatetime(variables('start'),'MM-dd-yyyy'),int(variables('count'))),'MM-dd-yyyy')`

max date from list : `@adddays(formatdatetime(variables('start')),int(variables('count')))`

[image]

output list of dates:

[image]

Comment: Please note that the OP hasn't asked a specific question, and just asked a broad "how to do it" question, without showing any work of their own. Best to just provide guidance on asking a better question, rather than writing a detailed answer